# Checking token expiry based on issued time and expires in

Tags: datetime, f#

What'd be the right way to check token expiry for 3rd party API calls.

**Token.fs**

```
type Token = {
    mutable access_token: string;
    mutable expires_in: string;
    mutable issued_at: System.DateTime;
}
```

I've added a field `issued_at` to track what time the token was issued and calculate expiry from the `expires_in` value.

`expires_in` value I get from the API is 86399984 (in ms) which is roughly about 24 hours. How do I approach expiry management, below is my attempt.

```
let token = {access_token = ""; expires_in = ""; issued_at = ""}
```

after api call

```
token.access_token <- result.access_token
token.issued_at <- DateTime.Now
token.expires_in <- result.expires_in // 86399984 (ms) ~ 24 hours
```

Now later when I want to check if token is expired or not before I request another token, how should I approach it? I want to check based on the `issued_at` - given `expires_in` instead of hard coding 24 hours because it may change.

---

**Edit**

Refactoring `Token` to better approach the problem. Discard the above code.

```
type Token = {
    mutable access_token: string;
    mutable expires_at: DateTime; // introducing a new field
}



let private credentials = {clientId = ""; clientSecret = ""; token = {access_token = ""; expires_at = DateTime.Now}}

let requestToken (claims: Credentials) =

    if credentials.token.expires_at < DateTime.Now then
         // call REST api
         let output = reader.ReadToEnd()

        let result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token>(output)      
        credentials.token.access_token <- result.access_token
        credentials.token.expires_at <- DateTime.Now + TimeSpan(0, 0, (int(result.expires_in))) // expires_in -> 86399984 (ms) ~ 24 hours
        credentials // return renewed token
      else
         credentials // return cached value
```

Comment: Write function that checks whether issued_at + expires_in < DateTime.Now.

Comment: thanks, do you recommend adding some buffer or time cushion?

Comment: I cannot recommend much as it depends only on your app requirements. But I would probably start from something simple and extend it if necessary.

Comment: I mean just to be safe, in case there's a lag in token renewal, something like this -> `issued_at + expires_in + 1000 < DateTime.Now`

Comment: 1) "+ 1000" - if the token management is sharp on the server, for this second some of your API queries may fail. 2) use "open System"

Comment: yes, I opened system and it worked, I've another error. `This expression was expected to have type    'string'    but here has type    'DateTime' `

Comment: I'm changing data type of issued_at to `DateTime`, that was the error. the other error is expires_in is string, `Type constraint mismatch. The type     'string'    is not compatible with type    'TimeSpan'` can you please run on your side and reply with a solution in the answer,

Comment: maybe if we introduce a field `expires_at` and set `DateTime.Now + result.expires_in` it will reduce the number of variables involved and we check `if token.expires_at < DateTime.Now`, the only problem is how do I convert string (milliseconds) into datetime

Comment: Use [TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.timespan.frommilliseconds?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_TimeSpan_FromMilliseconds_System_Double_) method for that

Comment: @AlexNetkachov When you say 1) + 1000 in your comments, it's meant to actually save us from failing, like I'm renewing token a second before expiring, right?. Maybe I should set it to +5000 what do you think?

Comment: 1) logically, `issued_at + expires_in + 1000` is equal to `issued_at + (expires_in + 1000)` => increasing `expires_in` by 1s gives the same effect as adding 1s to the sum. This looks wrong. Anyway, you can just test it yourself.

Comment: ok, got it, I should minus values from it, by the way it's hard to test because token renewal is every 24 hours by the server and I don't have control over it, so trying to have something without able to test